# Interactive commands using java Runtime.getRunTime.exec()

Tags: java, android, command-line, openssl, certificate

How can I send and receive multiple inputs using Runtime.getRunTime.exec().

For example if I wanted to run something such as openSSL to generate a csr, it will ask for things such as state, city, common name.. and so on.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream();
//print stuff p.getInputStream(); 
//Now i want to send some inputs 
out.write("test".getBytes()); 
//flush and close??? don't know what to do here
//print what ever is returned
//Now i want to send some more inputs 
out.write("test2".getBytes());
//print what ever is returned.. and so on until this is complete
```

> why not use p.getInputStream() to read what you need to send while
>   using out.write() to send data  accordingly.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
OutputStream out = p.getOutputStream();
//print stuff p.getInputStream();
out.write("test".getBytes()); 
out.close(); //if i don't close, it will just sit there 
//print stuff p.getInputStream();
out.write("test".getBytes()); // I can no longer write at this point, maybe because the outputstream was closed?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not use `p.getInputStream().read()` to read what you need to send while using `out.write()` to send data accordingly.

here is an example taken from: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html

```
String line;
OutputStream stdin = null;
InputStream stderr = null;
InputStream stdout = null;

  // launch EXE and grab stdin/stdout and stderr
  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime ().exec ("/folder/exec.exe");
  stdin = process.getOutputStream ();
  stderr = process.getErrorStream ();
  stdout = process.getInputStream ();

  // "write" the parms into stdin
  line = "param1" + "\n";
  stdin.write(line.getBytes() );
  stdin.flush();

  line = "param2" + "\n";
  stdin.write(line.getBytes() );
  stdin.flush();

  line = "param3" + "\n";
  stdin.write(line.getBytes() );
  stdin.flush();

  stdin.close();

  // clean up if any output in stdout
  BufferedReader brCleanUp =
    new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (stdout));
  while ((line = brCleanUp.readLine ()) != null) {
    //System.out.println ("[Stdout] " + line);
  }
  brCleanUp.close();

  // clean up if any output in stderr
  brCleanUp =
    new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (stderr));
  while ((line = brCleanUp.readLine ()) != null) {
    //System.out.println ("[Stderr] " + line);
  }
  brCleanUp.close();
```

Comment: that's what i am trying to do, but it seems like the write isn't working properly. I'll update the question with a little bit more explanation.

Comment: That works, I tried using flush before but I was trying so many different things I must have screwed up something else causing it not to work. Thanks!